# Can an AWS lambda be set up to retry if it fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that will sometimes fail because some other part of the system is not ready yet. In such cases, I want to retry the lambda in a couple seconds (preferably with an exponential backoff). How do I implement that?

It seems like feeding the lambda from an SQS or SNS queue might do the trick, but I can't figure out how to make it fail back to the queue and get retried.

Comment: for SQS, do not dequeue on failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Docs:

> Any Lambda function invoked asynchronously is retried twice

(You can increase that retry number) You can set a [Dead Letter Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) to keep all failed events for inspection, notification, etc. You can implement further logic to resend those events again or drop them, but IMHO you should have a dedicated lambda for that.